# How to make model jump to the first animation frame after enable it?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Unity C# question.

I have a model with animator controller. I need to make it "jump" to the first frame of its animation right before I disable the model via SetActive(false). So if I disable the model during its animation, and then enable it again, the model should reset its animation and appear in "default" state, so I could start animation from the beginning.

**The problem is that if I disable and enable the model during the animation, it appears frozen in the same frame which it has when I disabled it.**

I tried add a transition from "any state" to the default state, set transition duration to 0, and add "reatart" bool parametr to trigger the transition. And then:

```
myObject.SetBool("restart", true);
myObject.SetActive(false);
```

But it doesn't work, the object appears frozen in the middle of animation again.

I thought maybe it still needs some time for transition, so I tried as a workaround to use coroutine:
 - disable only mesh renderer
 - In Animator start transition to the first frame of animation 
(transition duration is 0)
- Wait a bit
 - SetActive(false)

But when I enable it again it is still frozen in the middle of the animation.
Why is it happening? And how can it be fixed?
Thank you very much in advance!

Hereis the code example:

```
public void disableObject(){
    StartCoroutine(disableObjectCoroutine());
}

public void enableObject(){
    myObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
    myObject.SetActive(true);
}

IEnumerator disableObjectCoroutine(){
    myObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
    myObject.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("restart", true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
    myObject.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("mainAnimation", false);
    myObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: *"- Wait a bit"* Why wait a bit? Just set the Animator start transition to the first frame of animation then quickly set it to inactive. Please update your question with your code.

Comment: @Programmer added! Thank you for the response!

Comment: Check the answer nipercop left. If that doesn't work then remove the WaitForSeconds stuff then move `myObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;` just before  `myObject.SetActive(false);` and after `myObject.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("mainAnimation", false);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try somethink like that:

```
int layer = 0;
int hashName = myAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).shortNameHash; //get current animation name
myAnimator.Play(hashName, layer, 0); // 0 means first frame
myObject.SetActive(false);
```